# Random, Array and char in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need to take a random element from an array of `char`s

1. C for hearts
2. Q for diamonds
3. F for clubs
4. P for spades

```
Random casuale = new Random()

char[] arraySuits = {'c', 'c', 'c', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p',};

location1S=casuale.next(arraySuits.length);
location2S=casuale.next(arraySuits.length);
```

There are two errors:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from `int` to `char`
- The method `next(int)` from the type `Random` is not visible

The errors are both at `casuale.next(arraySuits.length)` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Anyway, [`Random::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) doesn't do what you think it does. You probably want [`casuale.nextInt(vetSuits.length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there's a lot of confusion going on here

1. `location1S=casuale.next(arraySuits.length);` there's no `arraySuits` in view here, so we'll just assume you meant to call the array `arraySuits` when you declared it
2. [`casuale.next(arraySuits.length)` returns a `arraySuits.length`-bit random number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#next(int)), not a number between 0 and `arraySuits.length`. And it is a `protected` method anyway, so you can't use it unless your class inherits from `Random` (hence the second error message). You need to use [`casuale.nextInt(arraySuits.length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) instead.
3. You're trying to assign this random number to `location1S` which, according to your first error message and what your problem description implies (but your code does not actually show) is a `char`. Instead you should assign it an element of `arraySuits` with a random index, so `arraySuits[casuale.next(arraySuits.length)]`

All of this boils down to

```
Random casuale = new Random();

char[] arraySuits = {'c', 'c', 'c', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p'};

location1S = arraySuits[casuale.next(arraySuits.length)];
location2S = arraySuits[casuale.next(arraySuits.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first is that `location1s` and `location2s` are not defined as a type. They need to be given a variable type. In this case that would be `char`.

The second issue is that the `.next` method does not exist in java.random for `char`. You need to use the `.nextInt()` method that will pull a random value from the arrayList. See below for example.

```
Random casuale = new Random();

char[] arraySuits = {'c', 'c', 'c', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p',};
            
char location = arraySuits[casuale.nextInt(arraySuits.length)];

System.out.println(location); // prints out whatever random char was chosen.
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your assumptions on why OP's code is wrong are not :) See my answer for clarification.